# Get the last '/' or '\\' character in Python

Tags: python, string

If I have a string that looks like either

```
./A/B/c.d
```

OR

```
.\A\B\c.d
```

How do I get just the "./A/B/" part? The direction of the slashes can be the same as they are passed.

This problem kinda boils down to: How do I get the last of a specific character in a string?

Basically, I want the path of a file without the file part of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally [`os.path.dirname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) is used for this.

Comment: All the rest of the answers were right, but yours was shortest. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [os.path.split](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split).  It splits the path into head and tail... tail being the file, head being the path up to the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> p="./A/B/c.d"
>>> import os
>>> os.path.split(p)
('./A/B', 'c.d')
>>> os.path.split(p)[0]
'./A/B'
>>> os.path.dirname(p)
'./A/B'
>>> p.rsplit("/",1)[0]
'./A/B
```